# Аналог Vector в C#

Tags: c#

Какой существует аналог Vector'a из Java в C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ArrayList` из `System.Collections`.

Comment: Правда, сейчас его используют достаточно редко, т.к. чаще нужна типизированная коллекция - System.Collections.Generic.List<T> является аналогом ArrayList, но является обобщённым типом.