# Подобие vector в C#

Tags: c#, c++, vector

Недавно начал изучать C#, уже пользуясь C++. Интересует вопрос: есть ли в С# подобие вектора, как в плюсах? Это довольно удобная штука, и не хотелось бы терять такое сокровище :)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Аналог Vector в C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/17580/) - 2011 г.

Comment: не очень хорошо знаком с Джавой, а там про нее речь. возможно, векторы в плюсах и джаве схожи, так что я посмотрю, спасибо! но хотелось бы узнать что используют опытные специалисты

Comment: Список чтоли? `List<T>` Коллекций в C# много, на уровне стандартных библиотек гораздо больше сокровищ, чем в плюсах. Изучайте язык, всё найдется.

Comment: @aepot, судя по комментариям и ответам на такой вопрос замена большинства отвечавших на что-то вроде GPT будет благом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотри в сторону List - https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-7.0,

либо LinkedList - https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1?view=net-7.0